# Импорт CSV в базу данных MySQL

Tags: php, csv

Есть всем известный из сети скрипт импорта csv  в БД Mysql. Все работает как нужно, за одним большим и жирным минусом, который покрывает все плюсы. Импортировать нужно порядка 100 тыс строк. Все работает ужасно долго и в большинстве своем не заканчивается успехом.
Подскажите, как лучше переписать скрипт, чтобы он работал более устойчиво? Также есть возможность использовать PDO, но я в нем не силен.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //Получаем CSV файл
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //Обрабатываем в цикле CSV файл и добавляем данные в БД
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO price_minsk (brand, artikul, description, ostatok, kratnost, valuta, price) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,";","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

}
```

Также нашел такую функцию, которая, как говорят мануалы, работает быстро. Но как ее прикрепить в вышеозначенный скрипт?

```
function import_csv(
        $table,         // Имя таблицы для импорта
        $afields,       // Массив строк - имен полей таблицы
        $filename,      // Имя CSV файла, откуда берется информация 
                    // (путь от корня web-сервера)
        $delim=',',         // Разделитель полей в CSV файле
        $enclosed='"',      // Кавычки для содержимого полей
        $escaped='\\',      // Ставится перед специальными символами
        $lineend='\\r\\n',      // Чем заканчивается строка в файле CSV
        $hasheader=FALSE){      // Пропускать ли заголовок CSV

    if($hasheader) $ignore = "IGNORE 1 LINES ";
    else $ignore = "";
    $q_import = 
    "LOAD DATA INFILE '".
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename."' INTO TABLE ".$table." ".
    "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".$delim."' ENCLOSED BY '".$enclosed."' ".
    "    ESCAPED BY '".$escaped."' ".
    "LINES TERMINATED BY '".$lineend."' ".
    $ignore.
    "(".implode(',', $afields).")"
    ;
        return mysql_query($q_import);
    }
```

Comment: На всякий случай: использовать `addslashes()` для экранирования параметров запроса - некорректно

Answer (score 1):

Если вам разрешен доступ `LOAD DATA INFILE`, то конечно стОит использовать найденную вами функцию. Вместо цикла пишете просто:

```
import_csv(
    'price_minsk', 
    array('brand', 'artikul', 'description', 'ostatok', 'kratnost', 'valuta', 'price'),
    $FILES['csv']['tmp_name'],
    ';',
    '\''
);
```

Если вам эта операция не разрешена, то можно модифицировать вашу исходную функцию, но воспользоваться многострочным `INSERT INTO`

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 
    //Получаем CSV файл
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //Обрабатываем в цикле CSV файл и добавляем данные в БД $rowsToInsert = array();
    $rowsCount = 100;
    $insertStmt = 'INSERT INTO price_minsk (`brand`, `artikul`, `description`, `ostatok`, `kratnost`, `valuta`, `price`) VALUES ';
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";", "'")) {
        if (7 == count($data)) {
            $row = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data);
            $rowsToInsert[] = '("' . implode('", "', $row) . '")';
        }
        //Если набралось достаточное количество строк
        if ($rowsCount <= count($rowsToInsert)) {
            mysql_query($insertStmt . implode(', ', $rowsToInsert));
            $rowsToInsert = array();
        }
    }
    //Если остались строки для добавления
    if (!empty($rowsToInsert)) {
        mysql_query($insertStmt . implode(', ', $rowsToInsert));
        $rowsToInsert = array();
    }

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 
}
```

Можно попробовать увеличивать `$rowsCount` до разумных пределов. Главное, чтобы длина запроса не превысила лимит (`max_allowed_packet`).

При необходимости можно переписать это хоть на использование `mysqli` хоть на `PDO`. Это уже не принципиально.

Comment: А на PDO или xPDO матёрее будет по безопасности, быстродействию и т.д.?